# Can't scp from remote server to my local computer

Tags: terminal, scp

I'm having real trouble trying to move a file from a remote server onto my local computer.

I'm ssh'd into the remote server and currently inside one of the directories

Here's the code I'm using:

```
scp nsteinbe@minervagpvm02.fnal.gov:/minerva/app/users/nsteinbe/cmtuser/2014_Oct_TestVetoPlots/Minerva_v10r9p1/Tools/VetoWallTools/launchers/plot_macros/TestRun1.pdf /Users/noahsteinberg/Desktop/
```

There error I get is:

```
/Users/noahsteinberg/Desktop/: No such file or directory
```

I think I'm using the command correctly? Can any one give me hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to execute that command from your **local computer**.

If you are ssh'd into the remote server, you could execute the command as follows:

```
scp /minerva/app/users/nsteinbe/cmtuser/2014_Oct_TestVetoPlots/Minerva_v10r9p1/Tools/VetoWallTools/launchers/plot_macros/TestRun1.pdf nsteinbe@yourLocalComputer:/Users/noahsteinberg/Desktop/
```

It is also valid to use an ip address for *yourLocalComputer*. This way however only works if your computer and server are in the same network or the server has been configured to reach your local computer (e.g. no blocking firewall, dns entry, ...).

Comment: Forgive my ignorance,for the last part; nsteinbe@yourLocalComputer I assume that's not literally what I type in correct? my computer is under "noahsteinberg" not "nsteinbe" which is just my minerva username so I assume I'd put "noahsteinberg" for the first part, and then I put my ip address for "yourLocalComputer"?

Comment: Ok I used 

    nsteinbe@myipaddress:/Users/noahsteinberg/Desktop/ 

And I'm getting the message

    ssh: myipaddress: No route to host

Comment: Then your server does not know the route to your PC. Have you tried to execute the first command from your local computer? That should work if you have scp installed? scp nsteinbe@minervagpvm02.fnal.gov:/minerva/app/users/ ...

Comment: It worked!! I just needed to do it from my local computer. Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm glad that I could help you :) Edited my answer to clarify further.